# mongodb as round-robin-database

Tags: c, ruby, mongodb

I am using mongo-db for realtime analytics, I am getting 5 million
data points per day which will increase in future to 10 million at
least.

my question is:

Capped collections are circular so my data will be overwritten after
it reaches to the cap and i don't want to loose this data.

So what approach I should follow to keep old data and avoid that this data being overwritten but still being able to use capped since they are fast?

i was thinking in an algorithm like:

- rename current collection to old and drop current.
- append old to a search-friendly (not capped) collection

Comment: Is this one answered? Is there more data required?

Comment: could the new auto-expire TTL collections help this use-case?  http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/expire-data/ http://blog.mongodb.org/post/25933713094

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you may be going about this the wrong way. Instead of trying to "hack" the capped collection, why not just create a new collection for each time period?

So if you can handle 5-10M data points / day, then simply create a collection with the day as part of the name. You would get something like `db.data20101001` for November 1st and then `db.data20101002` for November 2nd.

As you stop writing old data that data will "fall" out of memory and will stop using RAM. By the same measure, the index for the current day (and maybe previous day) will likely always be in RAM, so inserts will continue to be fast while still maintaining history.

**Extra Step required by this solution:**

- You'll have to write some logic in your code to insert into the correct day (notice that new collections create themselves, so this is pretty simple)
- You'll need to set up a routine for deleting old data, typically something that goes back N days and does this: `db.data20100901.drop()`. You will not reclaim space, however Mongo will start using "older" data files.

So you're effectively managing the size of your collection by picking the number of active days.

Comment: Hi, i don't want to hack around the capped collection. I just want to have a collection to be used as RRD for my "network sensor" and another collection that will be used to do search over, to generate statistics and so on. I did update my algorithm. Does it make sense or do you still having the same idea about it? :-)

Comment: OK, so one of the problems with the capped collection is that you have no way of knowing what's going to "fall off". So the requirement to "not lose data" doesn't make any sense. You can't use a capped collection *and* not lose data. You say that "capped collections are fast", but they're not faster than regular collections of the same size. So you have two options here: 1. the way I did it above. 2. Write data to two collections: capped & archive. Rename and drop won't work, you'll destroy your data.

Comment: i was testing, i'm using C and mongo and i just finished friday. Capped is faster than normal collection. i did added my test code here https://github.com/vpereira/pcapreader if you create the collection as capped and then normal you will see. capped 20% faster.

Comment: So if capped is much faster for your situation, then you'll have to "double-write" to both the capped and the archive collection. MongoDB doesn't have triggers, so you'll have to rely on the code that does the writing.